# Arc length function given circle radius and two bounding line segments

Tags: geometry

Given points $A$, $B$, $C$ and $O$ and radius $r_1$ and $r_2$, find a function $F(r)$ that will return arc length of radius $r_1$ + $r$ bounded between two line segments $AB$ and $AC$. Point $O$ is the circle center, while points $B$ and $C$ lie on the circumference. Point $A$ can be anywhere in the area enclosed by $O$, $B$ and $C$. Radius $r_1$ is a distance from $O$ to $A$. Possible values of $r$ are $0 \le r \le r_2$

[image]

I want to integrate a function of arc length and radius $r_1$ + $r$ over the area enclosed by $A$, $B$ and $C$.

**Example**

Given input $r$, the function $F(r)$ will return arc length between points $PAB$ and $PAC$. Arc radius is the radius of circle centered at $O$ (not at $A$!).
[image: Example image]

Comment: What is r and how does it affect anything?  Is A fixed? Is r_1?  It seems like you are saying contradictory things and it's unclear what you want.  Please identify what is allowed to vary as input, and what is the output.  As is is I can not make heads or tails out of it.

Comment: My apologies. r is the input to function I want to find, given points A, B, C, and O. The r1 and r2 are distances dependent on these points. All points are fixed. The output of F is the arc length of radius r1+r bounded by lines AB and AC.

Comment: Just a remark/nitpicking, in general given two endpoints, there are two possible arcs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Important additional assumption**: we want to measure the "small" arcs with endpoints $PAB(r)$ and $PAC(r)$, and
the half-line originating from $O$ and going through $A$ must intersect those arcs.

If you need something more general, the approach below will fail, but it can be adapted.

The arc length in general is "radius" $\times$ "angular width (in radian)". We already know the radius is $r_1+r$, so we need to evaluate the angle. With my additional assumption on the half-line from $O$ through $A$, it suffices to evaluate the two angles $\widehat{PAB\ O\ A}$ and
$\widehat{A\ O\ PAC}$.
Below I go over how to obtain $\widehat{PAB\ O\ A}$, the other angle can be obtained in a similar way.

Let $x$ be the distance between $A$ and $PAB$, $\alpha$ the angle $\widehat{OAB}$ and $\theta$ our angle of interest $\widehat{PAB\ O\ A}$.
Angle $\alpha$ is a parameter of the problem, $x$ and $\theta$ vary with $r$.
We only need to know the cosine of $\alpha$, which can be obtained by the relation
$$
(r_1+r_2)^2=AB^2+r_1^2-2ABr_1\cos\alpha
$$
Next we want $x$:
\begin{align*}
&(r_1+r)^2=x^2+r_1^2-2xr_1\cos\alpha=(x-r_1\cos\alpha)^2-r_1^2\cos^2\alpha+r_1^2\\
&\iff\quad
(x-r_1\cos\alpha)^2=r_1^2+r^2+2r_1r+r_1^2\cos^2\alpha-r_1^2\\
&\iff\quad
x=r_1\cos\alpha\pm\sqrt{r^2+2r_1r+r_1^2\cos^2\alpha}
\end{align*}
Now because $x\ge 0$ and $\sqrt{r^2+2r_1r+r_1^2\cos^2\alpha}\ge\lvert r_1\cos\alpha\rvert$ we actually have
$x=r_1\cos\alpha + \sqrt{r^2+2r_1r+r_1^2\cos^2\alpha}$.
Next is $\theta$:
$$
x^2=(r_1+r)^2+r_1^2-2(r_1+r)r_1\cos\theta
$$
So if you put everything together you easily get $\cos\theta$ with respect to the various parameters.
Now the problem is that the identity $\theta=\arccos\big(\cos\theta\big)$
is only true when $0\le\theta\le\pi$. That's where my two additional assumptions come into play, since they guarantee $0\le\theta\le\pi$.

Comment: On a side note, I hope this isn't just to obtain the area of the circle enclosed by $AB$ and $AC$.

Comment: No, I need it for calculating integral over this area. Thanks for the answer, it works.